# Joomla4 plugin getBody

Tags: plugin, system-plugin, joomla-4.x

In Joomla 3.x versions I use JResponse to get and set the body.

```
function onAfterRender() {
          $content = JResponse::getBody();
          ...
    }
```

But in Joomla4 it returns **Class 'JResponse' not found**.
So how to get the body in Joomla4?

Thanks

Comment: For transparency, this question has also been posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58512896/2943403  There are some conflicting comments suggesting `JFactory::getApplication()->getBody() / setBody()` as an alternative... https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/323/12352  Another suggestion is found on the Joomla forum -- though not speaking directly about J4... https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=941835 have you tried `JApplicationWeb::getBody();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Application.WebApplication.html), `JApplicationWeb` seems to be alive and well in Joomla4.

> **since** 2.5.0

> **note** As of 4.0 this class will be abstract

- The getters:

  ```
    JApplicationWeb::getBody()
  ```

Or

```
    JFactory::getApplication()->getBody()
```

- The setters:

  ```
    JApplicationWeb::setBody()
  ```

Or

```
    JFactory::getApplication()->setBody()
```

---

Relevant references and examples:

- All of the classes from J3 to J4 conversion. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/libraries/classmap.php
- https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=941835
- [How to remove rel="nofollow" with Joomla Buffer?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/20879/12352)
- [Joomla/PHP How can a plugin append a css class to the body section?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10232/12352)
- [How plugin can check if meta tag exists?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9953/12352)
- [How to get rendered full page before returning to the browser?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23835/12352)
- [Problem with SSL after update to Jooma 3.4.1](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/9720/12352)

Comment: `JFactory::getApplication()->getBody()` is definitely recommended way.

Comment: Tell me more.  Better yet, tell everyone in an answer please.  You know better than me.  Why is one better than the other? @George

Comment: JFactory::getApplication returns an instance of JApplicationCms which is a subclass of JApplicationWeb. As a result rather than calling a non-static method in JApplicationWeb statically - grab the main application object and call the function in it's non-static intended way :)